# Knuth's Sandwich Theorem: requesting proof clarification

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, discrete-optimization

The question is about F6 of Section 8 ("Elementary facts about cones") in Donald Knuth's Sandwich Theorem (http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9312214.pdf). He claims to prove $(A \cap B)^* = A^* + B^*$ when $A$ and $B$ are closed cones, but when I go through the proof, it seems like he only gets
$$
A^* + B^* \subseteq (A \cap B)^* \subseteq (A^* + B^*)^{**}.
$$
The last expression is equal to the closure of $A^* + B^*$.

I agree with the proof if and only if $A^* + B^*$ is closed.
Why is $A^* + B^*$ closed?

Comment: Good one. I honestly don't know.

Comment: There's something wrong. Because if two closed cones can sum to a non-convex cone, these cones $A^*$ and $B^*$ are closed and could be taken as the $K_1$ and $K_2$ of your other question (take $A = K_1^*$, so that $A^* = K_1^{**} = K_1$ since $K_1$ is closed, similarly for $B$). So I have a problem with Knuth.

Comment: I did compute your counter example in this other question, and honestly you have a twisted mind for coming up with it... but I agree with it. So. Bleh.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva: Good to know I'm not the only one having a problem with Knuth.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you read the proof right. Not sure how to address your specific question so I'll just explain the proof instead.

The first step is to simply show that $(A \cap B)^* \supseteq A^* + B^*$ from first principles.

The rest of the proof is to show the reverse inclusion. He shows that $(A^* + B^*)^* \subseteq A^{**} + B^{**}$ by utilizing F2 and the fact that dual cones always contain the origin. Then he applies F2 again to obtain $(A^* + B^*)^{**} \subseteq (A^{**} \cap B^{**})^*$. But since both $A$ and $B$ are assumed to be closed cones, you can replace $A^{**}$ with $A$ and the same for $B$. You can also claim that $A^* + B^*$ is also a closed cone. Then you get $(A^* + B^*) \subseteq (A \cap B)^*$ thus completing the proof.

Comment: I have tried to clarify the question. I think you have some $+$ where you should have $\cap$. But anyway, the question is why $A^* + B^*$ is closed.